# fName set as Variant, still showing mismatch error when trying to stop macro if no file selected by GetOpenFileName function

Tags: vba, function, excel

I am trying to run my code with `GetOpenFileName` function in it. When I am not selecting a file, I am unsure of what is the value that is returned in variable `fName`. The way my code is right now, If I "Do Not" select a file, it returns the message box as written(which is what I want) but as I click ok, it takes me to a random spot in my workbook(something I also need help on), but main issue is, when I "Do" select a file to run, it gives me back a "Type mismatch error" even when my variable is defined as `Variant`. Without this addition to my code, the code runs great but I want to add this functionality. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
     Dim fName As Variant

     fName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="*.xlsx(*.xlsx),*.xls,*.xlsm (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", _
        Title:="Select a file or files", _
        MultiSelect:=True)

     If fName = "False" Then
        MsgBox "Select a file to proceed"

     Else

      Sheets("Main").Select

       If IsArray(Fname) Then
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    For N = LBound(Fname) To UBound(Fname)


        ' Get only the file name and test to see if it is open.
        FnameInLoop = Right(Fname(N), Len(Fname(N)) - InStrRev(Fname(N), Application.PathSeparator, , 1))
        If bIsBookOpen(FnameInLoop) = False Then

            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(Fname(N))
            On Error GoTo 0

 ' Sub CopyData()
 '
 ' CopyData Macro
 '

 '
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Columns("A:O").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("SupplierDeliveryPerfWall_MasterSheet").Activate



' ActiveSheet.Select
' ActiveSheet.Name = "Data"

Sheets("Data").Select

Range("A1").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                mybook.Close SaveChanges:=True
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "We skipped this file : " & Fname(N) & " because it is already open."
        End If
    Next N
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End If

' Change drive/directory back to SaveDriveDir.
ChDrive SaveDriveDir
ChDir SaveDriveDir



   'Insert data validation column

    Windows("SupplierDeliveryPerfWall_MasterSheet").Activate

    Sheets("Data").Select

    Range("A2:O2000").Select

    ' Unmerge data that is copied from Oracle

      Range("A2:O2000").UnMerge

    ' Sub sbInsertingColumns()

    'Inserting a Column at Column E for reason codes


     Range("E1").EntireColumn.Insert
     Range("E1").Select

     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Reason Code"

     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

    'Inserting a Column at Column F for Comments

     Range("F1").EntireColumn.Insert

     Range("F1").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Comments"
Range("F1").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

' Inserting data validation

Sheets("Main").Select
Range("AF2:AF2000").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("E2").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

' Insert Comment in data validation

Range("E2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="='Reason Codes'!$A$2:$A$500"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = "Select Reason Code"
    .ErrorTitle = "Select from list"
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = "If exception, enter in COMMENTS column"
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
Range("E2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="='Reason Codes'!$A$2:$A$500"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Select from list"
    .InputMessage = "Select Reason Code"
    .ErrorMessage = "If exception, enter in COMMENTS column"
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With


      Next

     End If
     End Sub
```

Comment: You're setting `MultiSelect` to True, so the return value (when you select at least one file) is an *array*, not a string.

Comment: @Tim - I tried to change what you said, on doing that the function ends properly and goes to the random location on one of the sheets, just like before. But when I select the file, instead of giving me an error, it is not processing the whole code, but just runs a small part of the code (just the functionality it was doing without any action added for no selection)

Comment: What's the rest of your code? I.e., the part within the `Else` block which is presumably "not running".

Comment: @David: Hi, do you by any chance have an email you can share with me, or you can directly email at my email as test mail and I can share with you the whole code. Please let me know if that would be possible for you.

Comment: That's kind of a last resort... why don't you update your question a little bit.  What is not clear to me -- which you should explain in your revision -- is "it is not processing the whole code". You're going to need to *show* the code, and indicate to the best of your ability which code is running, and which is not, and also describe how you arrive at these conclusions (e.g., what debugging techniques you use to make these determinations).

Comment: @David: Thank you so much for the solution you have provided below, it works good and also makes sense the way I understand. Being new to programming, it is very helpful that fellow members are helping understand the logic behind things. Anyways, I have added the rest of the code and what I meant by the code not running, was that it just showed "mismatch error" and I believe that was the only issue that I could not decipher what is the value being returned in Fname, now that you clarified, it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> main issue is, when I "Do" select a file to run, it gives me back a "Type mismatch error" even when my variable is defined as Variant.

This is because you have `MultiSelect:=True`. This is problematic because sometimes the result will be an *array* and other times (if the user cancels) it will be a *boolean*.  So first you need to test whether the return value is an array or not. If it's an array, the iterate the selected files. If not, then do the `MsgBox` prompt.

```
Sub foo()
Dim FileNames
Dim file

FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="*.xlsx(*.xlsx),*.xls,*.xlsm (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", _
        Title:="Select a file or files", _
        MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(FileNames) Then
    For Each file In FileNames

        'Do something to each file

    Next
Else
    'This really can't be anything other than FALSE:
    If Not FileNames Then
        MsgBox "No files selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

If you don't need to allow multi-select, then just use the `Dir()` function.

```
 fName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="*.xlsx(*.xlsx),*.xls,*.xlsm (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", _
    Title:="Select a file", _
    MultiSelect:=False)

 If Dir(CStr(fName)) = vbNullString Then 
    MsgBox "Select a file to proceed"
    Exit Sub
 Else
    'Do something to the file

 End If
```